# Keeping the code DRY when dealing with Blazor Navlinks

Tags: c#, asp.net, oop, blazor

The topic behind this issue may not be specific of nav links in Blazor but they have been one example of components where I could try some stuff without breaking all the applications I'm working on.
When You have a nav link in blazor the quickest thing you can do is hardcode the path such as:

```
<Navlink href="/products">Products</Navlink>
```

But then what if you have to add something later on, like for example a language path parameter that the user will change on the website? This parameter will be common across all of your components.

So to avoid having to change all nav links paths you write a function so that you will only need to change the code in one place such as:

```
<Navlink href"@NavigateToProducts">Products</Navlink>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public String Language {get; set;} // this comes from main layout page for example

    private void NavigateToProducts()
    {
        NavigationManager.NavigateTo("$/{Language}/products");
    }
}
```

You can also write a more general one like this that takes one or more parameters:

```
<Navlink href="@NavigateTo("products")">Products</Navlink>

@code {
    [Parameter]
    public String Language {get; set;] // this comes from main layout page for example

    private void NavigateTo(params String[] args)
    {
        var path = $"/{Language}"; // yeah could use a string builder
        foreach(var arg in args)
            path += $"/{arg}";

        NavigationManager.NavigateTo($"{path}");
    }
}
```

So this is all fine and great but in the case that you have more categories other than just products or even just other components you need to copy and paste this function in all of them just to have navigation for your nav links.

What I tried to do is first make a static class with extension methods so that:

```
<Navlink href="@(new String[]{"products"}.GetPath(Language))"

// In another file
public static class ExtensionMethods {
 
    public static String GetPath(this String[] parameters, String language)
    {
        var path = $"/{language}";
        foreach(var arg in args)
            path += $"/{arg}";

        return path;
    }
}
```

But I quickly realise this didn't solve anything, other than making the code more bloated with the necessity of making an array and call the method, you don't really solve the problem that if something needs to be added you have again to go and edit all your nav links and add a second parameter.

So what's something else you can do? You can make a service that you inject in all your components:

```
@inject IUriService UriService

<Navlink href="@(UriService.GetPath("products"))">Products</Navlink>

//In another file
public class UriService : IUriService 
{
    private readonly StringBuilder _strBuilder;
    private String _language;

    public UriService(NavigationManager navigationManager)
    {
        _language = // use navigation manager to get the language from url or whatever
        _strBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    }


    public String GetPath(params String[] pathParams)
    {
        if (pathParams == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(pathParams));

        _strBuilder.Clear();
        _strBuilder.Append($"/{_language}");
        foreach (var param in pathParams)
            _strBuilder.Append($"/{param}");
            
        return _strBuilder.ToString();
     }
}
```

Finally, if I need to change something common for all nav links I just need to come here!
This all works but when the User changes the language, how do I update my service with the new language?
I can make the variable _language property and just set it where I need, in my case in the navbar component:

```
// The HTML code for the navbar//
// A dropdown menu where you can choose the language that on click will trigger OnLanguageChanged()

@code {
    private void OnLanguageChanged()
    {
        // The logic for changing the language //
        UriService.Language = "en";
    }
}
```

Or to make it more encapsulated and more clear what you are doing I can make a method in the uri service:

```
public void UpdateLanguage(String newLanguage)
{
     _language = newLanguage;
}
```

Still, this seems messy and the variable can be changed at any point if you have the uri service injected. Also, the service is Transient at the moment, should it be a Singleton?
I don't know if there is a way to use events but I can't imagine being possible to subscribe to an event of the navbar component from the uri service. Or yes?
I know this has been a long post for what could be a trivial problem, but I'm kind of inexperienced with this stuff and it could be a good thing to remember when dealing with other similar situations.

Comment: `common across all of your components` - sounds like you want to leave your navlinks alone and pass that information in [cascading values](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/cascading-values-and-parameters?view=aspnetcore-5.0).

Comment: @GSerg i thought of that but again if i need to add parameters i need to still copy the function NavigateTo to all components and then modify it with a new parameter. Maybe it's fine, i'm not saying it isn't, i'm just saying that's what i would need to do. Or i could cascade an array of parameters and just add new parameters in it?

Comment: My suggestion is to build yourself a custom `NavLink` component that you use instead of `NavLink` - you can lift the code from here - https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/blob/main/src/Components/Web/src/Routing/NavLink.cs - and then either get your language from a Language Service you've registered or a cascaded value, though the service looks a better option if the user can change it while the SPA is running. Can post some starter code as an answer if you like the idea.

Comment: @ShaunCurtis Yes, the user can change the language while the app is running. It's a dropdown menu in the navbar which is shared ofc and it's always visible (it's written in the mainlayout page) so that when the user change the language, from a resource file all translations are applyied and all current stuff in the page gets rendere dagain. Yes you can go on and post the answer, i really like ur suggestion. Im interested on how you would structure the Language Service, for the rest i can archieve it myself and with the example.

Comment: give me a few hours.  I'll give you the structure then you can fill in the details.

Comment: I have a static method called Url on each page. E.g `Products.Url() ` or ProductDetails.Url(productId) etc. In your case there would be also a language parameter or some context that would contain the current language. You dont have to use stafic methods, you can use an transcient or scoped service that would keeo reference to the context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My Test project is called *NavTest* and it's Blazor server because it's quicker for testing.

Here's the very basic service.  A getter/setter and an Event.

```cs
using System;

namespace NavTest.Services
{
    public class LanguageService
    {
        public string Language 
        {
            get => _language;
            set
            {
                if (!value.Equals(_language))
                {
                    _language = value;
                    LanguageChanged?.Invoke(value, EventArgs.Empty);
                }
            }
        }

        private string _language { get; set; } = "en-GB"; // set the default language

        public event EventHandler LanguageChanged;

        public string GetLanguageUrl(string url)
            => $"{this.Language}/{url}".Replace("//", "/");
    }
}
```

Register the service in *Startup* - scoped which is essentially per user in Server.

```cs
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddRazorPages();
    services.AddServerSideBlazor();
    services.AddSingleton<WeatherForecastService>();
    services.AddScoped<LanguageService>();
}
```

The new NavLink inherits from `NavLink`. we:

1. Inject the LanguageService.
2. Register with LanguageService Language changed event
3. Override `OnParameterSet` to capture the base href and then update the href used.  We have to rebuild and change out `AdditionalAttributes` because it's read only.
4. Update the href and refresh the component on a language change event.

```cs
using NavTest.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Routing;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace NavTest.Components
{
    public class MyNavLink : NavLink
    {
        [Inject] private LanguageService LanguageService {get; set;}

        private string _basehref = string.Empty;
        private bool _firstrender = true;

        protected override Task OnInitializedAsync()
        {
            LanguageService.LanguageChanged += this.OnLanguageChanged;
            return base.OnInitializedAsync();   
        }

        protected override void OnParametersSet()
        {
            this.UpdateHref();
            base.OnParametersSet();
        }

        private void UpdateHref()
        {
            // Update the href in the Additional Attributes
            var href = string.Empty;
            var ats = new Dictionary<string, object>();
            if (this.LanguageService != null && this.AdditionalAttributes != null && this.AdditionalAttributes.TryGetValue("href", out var obj))
            {
                href = Convert.ToString(obj, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
                if (_firstrender)
                {
                    _basehref = href;
                    _firstrender = false;
                }
                // create a new attribute dictionary
                foreach (var attrib in this.AdditionalAttributes)
                {
                    ats.Add(attrib.Key, attrib.Value);
                }
                ats["href"] = $"{LanguageService.Language}/{_basehref}".Replace("//", "/");
            }
            // replace the existing dictionary
            this.AdditionalAttributes = ats;
        }

        private void OnLanguageChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            this.UpdateHref();
            _ = InvokeAsync(StateHasChanged);
        }
    }
}
```

Finally my test *Index.razor* looks like this:

```cs
@using NavTest.Services
@using NavTest.Components
@page "/"

<h1>Hello, world!</h1>

Welcome to your new app.

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12">
            <h2>Language Tester</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-4 form-label" for="txtcountry">
            Language
        </div>
        <div class="col-4">
            <input class="form-control" type="text" @bind-value="this.lang" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row mb-2">
        <div class="col-6">
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 text-right">
            <button class="btn btn-primary" @onclick="() => Click()">Update</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6">
            <MyNavLink href="/products/12"> Products</MyNavLink>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6">
            <div>@LangService.Language</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

@code {
    [Inject] LanguageService LangService { get; set; }

    string lang { get; set; }

    void Click()
    {
        LangService.Language = lang;
    }

    // example Navigate to
    void SomeMethod(string url)
    {
        NavManager.NavigateTo(LangService.GetLanguageUrl(url));
    }
}
```

I also added this into NavMenu to test it in another part of the page:

```cs
<li class="nav-item px-3">
    <MyNavLink class="nav-link" href="fetchdata">
        <span class="oi oi-list-rich" aria-hidden="true"></span> Fetch data
    </MyNavLink>
</li>
```

Should get you going in the right direction.

Comment: Wow thank you for this answer, gonna try it soon. Definetly will keep this pattern in mind in other scenarios